# getting Bash to execute external commands through proxy

Tags: bash

I want to add some extra logging, so I'd like bash to run "myevaluator cmdline" after expanding all the environment variables in cmdline, is that possible?

Update: basically I want to extend my bash history logging to include PID of the main process started by the command, and things from /proc/ tree.

For instance, if I run "java xyz" from bash command line, I want to log PID of the java process started by that command line.

Only way I can see to implement this would be to have "bash" call my custom evaluator giving it the final command-line, and then my evaluator would take care of starting the process and doing the logging

So the question is -- how do I get bash to call "myevaluator cmdline" whenever bash tries to execute an external process

Comment: You should add an example of what your input looks like and what you want your output to look like.

Answer (score 1):

Use `set -x` in your script ( or `/bin/bash -x you_script.sh` ) to print every line prepended with PS4 to stderr.